# Hover on mobile not working on my Shopify Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

I made a carousel with hover and clickable link, on desktop and mobile are working but on mobile when I click the image it will redirect me right away, but I want the first touch should be the hover image and on the second click will redirect me to url.

live demo
https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/

featured-collection

```
  <div class="page-width">
    <div class="proTitle">
      <h2>{{ section.settings.title }}</h2>
    </div>
      <div class="proText">
        {{ section.settings.text }} 
      </div>
    <div class="product-section-in">
      {% for product in collections[section.settings.collection].products %}
      <div class="prodBx">
        <div class="prodBx-imgBx">
          <div class="prod-img">
           <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="grid-link">
            
         {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
           <div class="featured-tag">
            <span class="badge badge--sale">
             <span class="gift-tag badge__text{% if sale_text.size > 9 %} badge__text--small{% endif %}">Save {{ product.compare_at_price | minus: product.price  | money | replace: '0,', ''}} </span>
            </span>
           </div>
         {% endif %}
            
        <div class="ImageOverlayCa"></div>
        {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
        <div class="reveal"> 
          <span class="product-additional">      
            <img class="" src="{{ product.images.last | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.images.last.alt | escape }}" />
          </span>
            <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" class="featured-image" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
        </div>      
        {% else %}
        <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" class="featured-image" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
        {% endif %}
        </a>
          
          </div>
          
          <div class="prod-name">
            <div class="prod-name-in">
              <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--
          <div class="pro_label service_type">
            <img src="{{ 'prod_icon_service.png' | asset_url }}">
          </div>
      -->
        </div>
        <!--<P class="proPrice">{{ product.price | money }}</P>-->
        
        <div class="proPrice">{% include 'product-slick-price', product: product, show_vendor: show_vendor %}</div>
        <a class="proBtn" href="{{ product.url }}">Shop Now</a>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for block in section.blocks %}
      <div class="prodBx">
        <div class="prodBx-imgBx">
          <div class="prod-img">
            <img src="{{ block.settings.img | img_url: 'master' }}">
          </div>
          <div class="prod-name">
            <div class="prod-name-in">
              <h2>{{ block.settings.name }}</h2>
 
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <a class="proBtn" href="{{ block.settings.link }}">{{ block.settings.btn }}</a>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% if section.settings.art_back %}
    <div class="favBack art-svg">
      {% include 'art-svg' %}
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="favBack">
      {% include 'favorite-back' %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if section.settings.arrow_back %}
    <div class="favLeft arrowBx">
    {% include 'grey-arrow' %}
      {% include 'white-curve' %}
    </div>
    <div class="favright arrowBx">
      {% include 'white-arrow' %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>


{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Collection",
    "settings": [
    {
      "type":"checkbox",
      "id":"grey_back",
      "label":"Enable Grey Backgrouond"
    },
    {
      "type":"checkbox",
      "id":"art_back",
      "label":"Enable art Backgrouond"
    },
    {
      "type":"checkbox",
      "id":"arrow_back",
      "label":"Enable Left Right Backgrouond"
    },
    {
      "type":"checkbox",
      "id":"custom_back",
      "label":"Enable Custom Backgrouond"
    },
    {
      "type":"text",
      "id":"title",
      "label":"Title"
    },
    {
      "type":"richtext",
      "id":"text",
      "label":"Text"
    },
      {
      "type":"collection",
      "id":"collection",
      "label":"Collection"
    }
],
"blocks":[
  {
    "type":"Image",
    "name":"Service",
    "settings":[
    {
      "type":"image_picker",
      "id":"img",
      "label":"Image"
    },
    {
      "type":"text",
      "id":"name",
      "label":"Product Name"
    },
    {
      "type":"text",
      "id":"reviewNumber",
      "label":"Review Number"
    },
    {
      "type":"text",
      "id":"price",
      "label":"Price"
    },
    {
      "type":"text",
      "id":"btn",
      "label":"Button Name"
    },
    {
      "type":"url",
      "id":"link",
      "label":"Button Link"
    },
    {
      "type":"checkbox",
      "id":"pro_type",
      "label":"Service Type"
    }
  ]
  }
],
"presets":[
  {
    "name":"Collection",
    "category":"New"
  }
]
  }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

css

```
.prod-img:hover .product-additional { visibility: visible;  opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0);-moz-transform: translateX(0); -ms-transform: translateX(0); -o-transform: translateX(0);transform: translateX(0);}
```

Comment: in live demo hover is working, please specify more information (browser for example)

Answer (score 1):

Hover events do not fire on mobile browsers (because hovering is an action you can only do with a a pointing device like a mouse)

If you want this interaction, you'd have to track how many times you clicked each item, so the first click switches the image and the second one takes you to the desired page.

I would advise against it because it's bad UX and cumbersome to program with vanilla JS

Comment: Hover styles actually are triggered on tap/click on mobile devices, but if the element being tapped also has a link or event handler then the browser will execute that action. You're not wrong about this being a terrible idea for mobile UX though.